# Averaging a flatfile with dynamic columns greater than 2gb in SSIS

Tags: file, dynamic, ssis, header, flat

I need to summarise a huge csv file produced as the output from another process. The file varies, and can have different headers. Every file has a string field in col1, a look number (integer) in col 2  then decimals for cols 3 through x, where x changes, as do the headers. The col1 repeats for each loop.

I need to average everything from col 3.

I know I can set up a static flat file connection for each file but I'm looking for a way to get this to work automatically for any file of the same format. Some of them up to 5gbs.

Is this even possible?

I'm using SSIS version 2012 atm.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into importing this data into a SQL database?  Create a staging table, import all the data, then use SQL to do your aggregation.

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for the suggestion. I mean... is that the answer? I should say I'm not really any expert in these things, just a fast learner

Comment: I deal with a lot of flat files and similar processes and that is how I would do it.  Only other way would be to import it into memory and do the calculations that way, and with such large files that is not a good way to go

Comment: I know I could read off the header to get the metadata I need, then do a create table programmatically... Is that the best way?

Comment: I would dump it into a database for sure. Why do you need to create a table programmatically? Just create the table beforehand. Or do you have a lot of files with different formats? SSIS isn't the best for handling that...

Comment: Hi Jacob. Because I don't know how many columns are in it, and I want to automate this averaging process.

Answer (score 0):

Without business rules outlined for you about how the data can vary such a data load would be very risky due to the dynamic nature of the file.

Since SSIS operates based on rigid (non-fluid) metadata descriptors, such an endeavor is not best suited for SSIS in my view.